# ImageButton change background colour on click

Tags: colors, android, android-button

How I can make my ImageButton change its color when I click it?

I want to do something like this :

> Button(Blue) -> Click -> Button(Red) -> Click -> Button(Blue) -> Click
>   -> Button(Red)

when I click it switch color and when I click again it goes back to original.

I've tried to do like this:

```
mTrashFlag = !mTrashFlag;
ImageButton bt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.trash_button);
if(!mTrashFlag)
{
    bt.setBackgroundColor(0x4CB8FB);
}
else
{
    bt.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000);
}
```

but it didnt work. It changed color to white and then I couldn't click on it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass a [Color](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html) class attribute instead of the hexa code directly :

```
if(!mTrashFlag)
{
    bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CB8FB"));
}
else
{
    bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Also, you have to register a [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.htmlhttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) on the button to get notified when it's clicked, so the final code is :

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    // 'v' is the clicked view, which in this case can only be your button
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mTrashFlag = !mTrashFlag;

        if (!mTrashFlag)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4CB8FB"));
        }
        else
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked ! . and by the way i dont need to register like that because in the xml layout i used onclick=my_function..

Comment: Oh ok I was not sure about that. Glad it worked ! Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use following way..

```
String color = "b";
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.buttonlayout);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onButtonClick(R.id.btn);
            }
        });
}

public void onButtonClick(int id) {

        if (color.equals("b")) {
            findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            color = "r";
        } else if (color.equals("r")) {
            findViewById(id).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            color = "b";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you Can Try This code:

```
ImageButton mButton;
int mTrashFlag=0;

 **get the id and implement the on click listener**


 mButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.bt);
  mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

 public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    if(mTrashFlag==0){



        mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);


        mTrashFlag =1;
    }

    else if(mTrashFlag==1){

        mTrashFlag=0;

        mButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include the alpha value (FF)
so 
`bt.setBackgroundColor(0x4CB8FB);`
will be
 `bt.setBackgroundColor(0xFF4CB8FB);`