# Keep button in pressed state

Tags: android

I my application, I have to create a set of button. Say *button1 & button2*.

**Requirements:**

When a button is clicked it should remain in pressed state.
Only one button can remain pressed at a time. That is, If button1 is in pressed state & button2 is clicked, then Button1 should beecome unpressed and button2 should be changed to remain in pressed state.

I've 2 drawables, one for pressed & one for unpressed. But how should I code my selectors for this?
And, what changes do I need to do in my java code ?

I tried using checkbox button, but my drawables contains layer-list, which was creating problem.

Thank You

Comment: You may want to have a look at `android.widget.RadioButton`.

Comment: You can get idea from : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20161935/1405983

Comment: the pls post your drawable xml and all relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like a classic implementation of `RadioButton`. Make sure to use them in the same `RadioGroup` and you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

You can try toggle button or swtich widget(only for higher versions)
else can try following code:-

```
Button button1;
    Button button2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                button1.setPressed(true);
                button2.setPressed(false);
                return true;
            }
        });

        button2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                button2.setPressed(true);
                button1.setPressed(false);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item 
    android:state_selected="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/selected_image" />
<item 
    android:drawable="@drawable/unselected_image" />
```

when First button get pressed then make it selected **true** and make second button selected **false** and visa - verse when second button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

How about using imageviews and changing drawables at each click.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this using:

```
button1.setEnabled(false);
```

For example-

```
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            button1.setEnabled(false);
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            //do something
        }
    });
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button1.setEnabled(true);
            //do something 
        }
    });
```